# Different Hausdorff topologies with the same continuous mappings

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Fix a set $X$. For a topology $\tau$ on $X$, let $F_\tau = \{f: X \to X \mid f \text{ continuous w.r.t. } \tau\}$. What would be an example of a set $X$ and two Hausdorff topologies $\tau$ and $\sigma$ on $X$ such that $\tau \neq \sigma$ but $F_\tau = F_\sigma$?

Comment: Maybe explore the very limited world of topologies on finite sets, with maybe 4 or 5 elements.

Comment: @DanAsimov If the set is finite there is only one Hausdorff topology: the discrete one. So, this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, so much for that idea. Here's another possibly bad idea: What if we define an alternative topology on the real line with a base of half-open intervals [a, b) instead of (a, b). Will this have the same continuous maps ℝ → ℝ as the standard topology?

Comment: @DanAsimov, I think that one is disconnected, so for example there is a continuous map whose image is exactly $\{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to find an example is via [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4563407/473276) fact.

In more detail: suppose $(X, \tau)$ is a nontrivial Hausdorff space with the property that any $\tau$-continuous function $X \to X$ is either the identity or constant. Let $f: X \to X$ be any non-identity bijection of $X$ (eg one that swaps two elements). Let $\sigma$ be the topology on $X$ that makes $f: (X, \tau) \to (X, \sigma)$ into a homeomorphism (ie "transport the structure along $f$"). Then $F_\tau$ and $F_\sigma$ both consist only of the identity function and the constant functions. But $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are not equal, because otherwise $f$ would be a continuous function from $(X, \tau) \to (X, \tau)$.

Comment: But they are still homeomorphic. Is there an example where the topologies are not homeomorphic?

Comment: @psl2Z, the question didn't say anything about non-homeomorphic. But yes, you can get that. For example, any proper subcontinuum of the Cook continuum can't be homeomorphic to the Cook continuum, so this gives two non-homeomorphic Hausdorff spaces of the same cardinality whose only continuous self-maps are the identity of constant.

Comment: @Soma, that's not so hard - $\sigma$ is just the collection of all sets of the form $f(U)$ where $U \in \tau$. The idea is to use $f$ to "relabel" the points of $X$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Comment: Thanks!! Very nice example