# Does a countably infinite preorder admit continuum many endomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

The following assertion was made while discussing a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4231158) regarding [Alexandrov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) in topology.

> Every countably infinite preorder has exactly continuum many endomorphisms.

Here, a [preordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) is a set $P$ together with a relation $\le$ that is reflexive and transitive.  Preordered sets form a category where the morphisms between two preorders are the *monotone functions* (satisfying $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$).

So assume $P$ is countably infinite.  The question asks the number of monotone maps from $P$ to itself, which should be $2^{\aleph_0}$. (It cannot be more than that, since that is the number of set functions from $P$ to itself.)

Below is a partial proof.  How can the last step be completed?

---

Step 1: Given the preorder, there is an associated equivalence relation defined by $x\sim y$ if $x\le y$ and $y\le x$.  If one of the equivalence classes, say $A$, is infinite, any map that sends $A$ to itself and fixes elements not in $A$ is monotone, and there are continuum many such maps.  Otherwise, every equivalence class is finite.  So the quotient structure $P/\sim$, which is a [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) when given the natural induced order relation, is infinite and every monotone self-map of $P/\sim$ lifts to at least one monotone self-map of $P$.  So without loss of generality we can assume $P$ is a poset.

Step 2: If the order relation on $P$ is the identity relation (= elements are only comparable to themselves), then any map from $P$ to itself is monotone, and there are countinuum many such maps.  So we can assume there are at least two distinct comparable elements, say $x_0\le x_1$.

Step 3: Suppose $P$ has an infinite antichain $D$ (= no two elements are comparable). Any subset $A\subseteq D$ gives rise to an [upper set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) $A^{\uparrow}=\{x\in P:x\ge a \text{ for some } a\in A\}$, and this upper set uniquely determines $A$ as its set of minimal elements.  So there are continuum many upper sets $U$ in $P$.  For each such $U$, the map sending $U$ to $x_1$ and the complement of $U$ to $x_0$ is monotone.  So we have countinuum many such maps.  We can now assume $P$ has no infinite antichain.

Step 4: As shown for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96436), $P$ must then contain an infinite chain (= all elements comparable).

Step 5: handle the case of an infinite chain ...

---

(Added later) From the comment to the answer, we also conclude:

> Every infinite preorder has at least continuum many endomorphisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $P$ contains an infinite chain, it either contains an infinite strictly increasing sequence or an infinite strictly decreasing sequence.  We may assume without loss of generality that it contains a strictly increasing sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.  If there exists $b\in P$ such that $b>a_n$ for all $n$, pick one such $b$ and call it $a_\infty$.  Now define $f:P\to P$ by $f(x)=a_n$ for the least $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\not<x$, or $a_\infty$ if no such $n$ exists.  Then $f$ is an endomorphism and the image of $f$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$.  In either case, the image of $f$ has continuum many endomorphisms which we can compose with $f$ to get continuum many different endomorphisms of $P$.

Comment: Followup question.  It seems that our complete proof consisting of the five steps above (including your answer) goes through in the same fashion if $P$ is uncountable.  And we can conclude: Every infinite preorder admits at least continuum many endomorphisms.  Would you agree?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks.